# Laravel response function only return 200?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For example:

```
response()->json(['error' => 'invalid', 401]);
response()->json(['success' => 'success', 200]);
```

These two ways are all response 200.If I want to return 200 when success,but 401 when error happened.How can I achieve this.

Comment: Put the status code outside of the array. It should be an argument, not an item in the json.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The 401 or 200 should be the second argument of the json function like this

```
response()->json(['error' => 'invalid'], 401);
response()->json(['success' => 'success'], 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
return response()->setStatusCode()->json
```